# How can I parallelize command sha256sum or other hashing commands?

Tags: hashsum, parallelism, multithreading

I want to parallelize hash calculation process because I have a very large amount of file counts and sizes.
When I see CPU usage of these commands, I get upset because they are only using one thread; how can I parallelize these?

```
sha256sum foo.mp4
OR
openssl -dgst sha256 foo.mp4
```

Comment: hashing algorithms are inherently serial, but for large file _count_ you can of course just hash multiple files at a time by running multiple instances of the command

Comment: @Fox *Some* hashing algorithms are inherently serial, but not all.

Answer (score 3):

For parallelizing across files you can use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel sha256sum ::: *
```

Parallelizing hashing for a single file can be done with certain hash functions using a Merkle tree. `b3sum` is such a tool.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could upgrade to a CPU which supports hardware SHA256 calculations like newer Intel or AMD CPUs. My Ryzen 3700X is blazingly fast at calculating SHA256 hash sums, a lot faster than for calculating MD5 which is a much simpler algo. Check for `sha_ni` in `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Alternatively you could use [Blake3](https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3) which is a lot (almost 15 times) [faster](https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/blake3-3716708235ac) even when implemented purely in software:

[image]

Comment: useful info, +1, but orthogonal to parallel processing.  Even with faster HW and algorithm, there are still benefits to running one hashing process per CPU core/thread rather than just one total.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` has a `-P` option for running multiple jobs in parallel.   It's nowhere near as flexible as Ole Tange's `parallel` program, but it's fine for most simple parallelisation tasks.

For example:

```bash
find . -name '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -0r -n 1 -P 0 openssl dgst -sha256
```

- `-P 0` tells xargs to run as many jobs in parallel as possible (e.g. on my 32 thread Threadripper 1950x, it will run 32 `openssl` jobs in parallel)
- `-n 1` tells xargs to run each job with only one argument.    While 1 job is sub-optimal for `openssl dgst` which can process many filenames on a command line, you will almost always want to use the `-n` (or `-L`) option with `xargs -P`.

  Otherwise it will try to fit as many args onto each command line as it can - usually resulting in just one job unless you have many tens of thousands of arguments.  On Linux, the command line length limit is typically 2 million characters, 2097152 (check with `getconf ARG_MAX`).  That allows for a lot of filenames.

  The optimum is to count how many args you have and divide that by the number of jobs you want to run in parallel.  e.g.

  ```bash
  t=32
  numfiles=$(find .//. -name '*.mp4' | grep -c //)
  let n=numfiles/t
  find . -name '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -0r -n "$n" -P "$t" openssl dgst -sha256
  ```

Note: `-P` is not a standard POSIX option for xargs.  Requires GNU or *BSD xargs.  Maybe some other versions too.